# Ordered field property

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let F be an ordered field. Suppose that $a\in F$  and $a \neq 0$. Prove that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $(a^n)^{-1}=(a^{-1})^n$

Attempt:

$(a^{-1})^n(a)^n=(a^{-1}a)^n=1$ so $(a^{-1})^n$ is the unique multiplicative inverse of $(a)^n$ thus  $(a^n)^{-1}=(a^{-1})^n$.

I don't know if the algebraic property $(c)^n(d)^n=(cd)^n$ is allowed to be used since it hasn't been proved I have a feeling this should be proved by induction.Is my approach correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. As for $c^nd^n=(cd)^n$, it follows from the fact that multiplication in a field is commutative.

Comment: This has nothing to do with  ordered fields, and less to do with real analysis: it's true in any group.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct. For the lemma you can use simple induction:

*Start.* $cd=dc$ by commutativity of multiplication.
*Step.* Assume that $c^n d^n=(cd)^n$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$. Then (using commutativity of multiplication again) $c^{n+1} d^{n+1}=(c^n c) (d^n d) = c^n d^n c d \overset{\text{Inductive assumption}}=(cd)^ncd=(cd)^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

The property $(xy)^n=x^ny^n$ holds in fields. But there's a much simpler proof.

The statement is clearly true for $n=0$, as $(a^0)^{-1}=1=(a^{-1})^0$.

Suppose the statement holds for $n$. Then
$$
(a^{n+1})^{-1}=(a^na)^{-1}=a^{-1}(a^n)^{-1}=a^{-1}(a^{-1})^n=(a^{-1})^{n+1}
$$
where I used the fact that $(xy)^{-1}=y^{-1}x^{-1}$ and $x^{n+1}=x^nx=xx^{n}$.

Note that this proof is valid in every (multiplicative) group, even not abelian.